# Issue with Mixitup plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi everyone 
[HERE](http://studiodentisticocova.com/casi-clinici-portfolio/) you can see the site in action.
 Use it clicking on a thumbnail and then use the filter, you can see that the thumbnail on the second line go up outside of the screen and then come back.

I'm using MIXITUP plugin.

This is the code that I applied to "click" event on filter to collapse the blue divs and remove the padding under the thumbnail.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){             
                var divcasiclinici = $(".divcasiclinici");
                var viewportWidth = $(window).width();
                if(viewportWidth > 768){
                    $("#filtroclinici").click(function(){
                        $('.mix').css({ paddingBottom: '0px' }, 0);
                        $(divcasiclinici).css("display", "none");
                        $(".frecciaportfolio").css("display", "none");
                    });
                };
```

Here the code of the first element/line/thumbnail (Sorry for the indentation but WP make a mess! )

```
<ul id="Grid">
<li class="mix dentosofia"><div class="triggerport" id="thumbclinico1"><div class="frecciaportfolio"></div>
<img src="http://localhost/Wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/maria_prima.jpg" style="height:auto;"/>
<div class="nomicasistudio">Maria</div></div>

<div class="divclinicoabsolute">
<div style="clear:both;" id="contfascia" class="divcasiclinici divclinico1">
<div class="fascione" style="background-color:#1fbeca;"></div>
<div class="close"><img src="http://studiodentisticocova.com/img/close.png"/></div>
<div class="total titlecasistudio" style="color:white;" >Dentosofia</div>
<div class="total nomicasistudio">Maria 14 anni</div>
<div id="team-container">
<div class="casistudio one_fourth column provamobile" >
<img src="http://localhost/Wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/maria_prima.jpg" style="height:auto;"/>
<div class="nomicasistudio">Maria Prima</div>
</div>
<div class="casistudio one_fourth column provamobile lastmobile" >
<img src="http://localhost/Wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/maria_dopo.jpg" style="height:auto;"/>
<div class="nomicasistudio">Maria Dopo</div>
</div>
<div class="clearmobile">
<div class="casistudio one_fourth column provamobile" >
<img src="http://localhost/Wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/Maria-2.jpg" style="height:auto;"/>
<div class="nomicasistudio">Sintomi iniziali</div>
</div>
<div class="casistudio one_fourth column last provamobile" >
<img src="http://localhost/Wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/Maria-3.jpg" style="height:auto;"/>
<div class="nomicasistudio">Dopo 14 mesi</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="predesccasistuido">
<div class="one_half column casostudio" >
<div><span class="subtitlecasistudio" style="color:white;">Diagnosi</span></div>
<h6>Il soggetto presentava una seconda classe (mandibola indietro rispetto all’arcata superiore)</h6>
</div>
<div class="one_half column casostudio last">
<div><span class="subtitlecasistudio" style="color:white;">Risultato</span></div>
<h6>Dopo 14 mesi utilizzando l’attivatore si può notare come il problema della seconda classe si sia completamente risolto. È visibile anche un netto miglioramento a livello dei denti superiori con una forte riduzione dello sventagliamento degli stessi.</h6>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

</li>
```

I've no idea how to solve it, I think I should add a delay to the animations of the plugin but I'm not able.
Does anyone have an idea?

SOLVED!
I added a Settimeout ito the plugin

```
setTimeout(function() {  
 goMix(config.filter, null, null, $cont, config); 
},100);
```

Comment: Provide your solution by posting the answer, so others will see it.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED! I added a setTimeout into the plugin to add a delay of 100ms so in that time can happen all the actions I wrote previuosly (the click on the filter)

Modified the plugin:

```
setTimeout(function() {  
     goMix(config.filter, null, null, $cont, config); 
    },100);
```

So i give the time to complete this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){             
                var divcasiclinici = $(".divcasiclinici");
                var viewportWidth = $(window).width();
                if(viewportWidth > 768){
                    $("#filtroclinici").click(function(){
                        $('.mix').css({ paddingBottom: '0px' }, 0);
                        $(divcasiclinici).css("display", "none");
                        $(".frecciaportfolio").css("display", "none");
                    });
                };
```